# Disagreement over termination date

Tags: united-states, termination, benefits

I am resigning. My current employer terminates my benefits immediately. My prospective employer wants to start me at the end of November. I requested to end my employment the day before. However, that falls on a weekend. Current employer sent a resignation letter that goes all the way to before the Thanksgiving holiday. Can I dispute this so that I can keep my benefits without any gap? I live in Washington State in the United States.

Comment: Which state? A lot of employment regulations are by state.

Comment: Which country are you in? If your regulations vary by state, which state are you in?

Comment: OP, could also clarify what benefits you're talking about? The first answer has assumed that you're talking about health benefits.

Comment: Can you start working on the new employer right now?

Answer (score 2):

> My prospective employer wants to start me at the end of November. I requested to end my employment the day before. However, that falls on a weekend. Current employer sent a resignation letter that goes all the way to before the Thanksgiving holiday.

Unless there are specific laws to the contrary (and this is not legal advice), a company is not obligated to honor your notice period. Just as you are free to resign, an employer is also free to terminate employment at any time.

> Can I dispute this so that I can keep my benefits without any gap?

You can dispute this but it's doubtful you have any standing or leverage to change their minds. You should however have the option to continue at least your health care coverage under COBRA (assuming US location), although you would be responsible for the premiums. That way you would not have any gap in coverage.

Instead of trying to change the effective date of your resignation, I would explain your situation to the HR/benefit groups of both companies, to see what your options are and how they might be able to help you. If COBRA premiums are cost-prohibitive for you, it's possible your new employer could subsidize some or all of those expenses.

Comment: Please do not try to guess locations. This is wildly wrong for large parts of the world. Please ask for clarification instead, or at least mark your answer with a fat disclaimer that for whatever reason you assume the OP is in the US.

Comment: *...for whatever reason...* @nvoigt Probably the "gap in benefits" part of the question.

Comment: @BSMP You think the US is the only country where you can have a gap in benefits between jobs? I would have thought "Thanksgiving" would be the better hint.

Comment: *You think the US is the only country where you can have a gap in benefits between jobs?* @nvoigt No, but it's also not the only country that celebrates Thanksgiving.

Comment: Your first sentence is tautological. Basically you are saying that if they are not obligated, they are not obligated.

Comment: This is what confuses me. Does it become a termination then? I feel they owe some explanation other then sending me a form that is different than what we had discussed with no explanation.

Comment: @AdamO I meant termination in the general sense, as in the ending of employment, not that you were fired for cause. Perhaps I'm confused as to the sequence of events -- it sounds like you resigned and were expecting to be able to serve out your notice period. Is that correct?

Comment: @AdamO Also, what is your country/region/state/province?

Answer (score 0):

Check your contract. It will either say that you or the company can terminate your employment at any time for any reason (IE in U.S. "At Will" States). Or it will specify the notice period(s) that you and the company need to give each other.

If the contract says there's no notice period, then there's probably nothing you can do. You can ask, but they're under no obligation to say yes.

If the contract says there is a notice period then while they can tell you to stop coming to work, they do have to keep you on payroll until the period ends.

This can also vary quite a bit depending on which country you're in.

You can always ask your new employer if it's possible to put you on their coverage early. Or see if there's something else you can work out.

I hope that helps!